# Keras: input_shape=train_data.shape produces "list index out of range"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use Keras to build a CNN-LSTM network. However, I have trouble finding the right shape for the first layer's `input_shape` parameter.

My `train_data` is a ndarray of the shape `(1433, 32, 32)`; 1433 pictures of size 32x32.

As found in [this example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py), I tried using `input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]`, which results in the same error as `input_shape=train_data.shape`:

> IndexError: list index out of range

The relevant code is:

```
train_data, train_labels = get_training_data()
# train_data = train_data.reshape(train_data.shape + (1,))
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(
      CONV_FILTER_SIZE[0],
      CONV_KERNEL_SIZE,
      activation="relu",
      padding="same"),
   input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
```

All the results I found for this error were produced under different dircumstances; not through `input_shape`. So how do I have to shape my Input? Do I have to look for the error somewhere completely different?

**Update:**
Complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "trajecgen_keras.py", line 131, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
File "trajecgen_keras.py", line 85, in main
    input_shape=train_data.shape))
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 467, in add
    layer(x)
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py", line 211, in call
    y = self.layer.call(inputs, **kwargs)
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 168, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3335, in conv2d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 753, in convolution
    name=name, data_format=data_format)
File "/home/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 799, in __init__
    input_channels_dim = input_shape[num_spatial_dims + 1]
File "/home/../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 521, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Its not clear what or where the error is produced, you should include the complete stack trace produced by python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a `TimeDistributed` layer combined with a `Conv2D` layer, it seems that `input_shape` requires a tuple of length 4 at least: `input_shape = (number_of_timesteps, height, width, number_of_channels)`.

You could try to modify your code like this for example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(
      CONV_FILTER_SIZE[0],
      CONV_KERNEL_SIZE,
      activation="relu",
      padding="same"),
    input_shape=(None, 32, 32, 1))
```

More info [here](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/).

Comment: I am getting the same error, but I followed all the appropriate steps that can be found online.  I have a list of 39 numpy arrays, shape 4x10.  I reshaped by list to be a numpy array size 39x4x10x1, and the input shape to the convolution layer is (39,4,10,1).  I am doing one timedistributed convolution layer followed by an LSTM layer.  My input to model.fit is my training set (an numpy array size 39x4x10x1) and the prediction for each element (also a numpy array size 39x4x10x1) with 10 epochs and batch_size = 1.  What might be causing the error for me?